# AudioRecord.read() method blocks indefinitely on Android 4.3+

Tags: android, audiorecord

After the next sequence AudioRecord.read() method blocks indefinitely on Android 4.3+:

```
1) Create Audio record object in first activity.
2) start(), read(), stop(), release()
3) Open second Activity
4) Create Audio record object in second activity.
5) start(), read() <- "read" method blocks indefinitely, and i get this warnings in LogCat:
```

LogCat:
    01-06 12:29:45.797: W/AudioRecord(20225): dead IAudioRecord, creating a new one from start()
    01-06 12:29:45.799: I/AudioFlinger(185): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb3060000 ready to run
    01-06 12:29:45.805: W/AudioPolicyManager(185): releaseInput() releasing unknown input 1276

Some code:

```
int min_buff_size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 
                    read_samplerate, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
                    min_buff_size);
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please add some more code? What are you going to do in your Application?

Comment: @Xry Later, sorry. After testing on multiple devices with different versions of Android (4.3+) this bug manifested itself only at Android 5.0+ (Nexus 5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem may be caused by not releasing the audiorecord after each use. To solve your problem, you may follow those steps:

1. Restart you phone and do not run anything when it start
2. Add code to release your audiorecord somewhere that you want to stop, e.g. onPause().

   `audiorecord.stop();`

   `audiorecord.release();`
3. Run test again.

Hope this help.

Comment: 1) Sometimes after a reboot method record.read() blocks indifenitely! Bug in OS?
2) Already added. See folowing code:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b509c15d19c76939a7b5

Comment: Have you tried to move audiorecord as global variable instead of local variable in thread?